# Run TestNG methods directly in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, testng

When I run any TestNG method/class directly from IntelliJ (by right-clicking) every test method is executed three times, ie. three instances are started. In the Run view I see: testMethod, testMethod(1), testMethod(2.) The last method always passed.

When I run a gradle task every method is executed once. The gradle task looks like:

```
task testSomething(type: Test) {
  useTestNG() {
    includeGroups 'testGroup1'
  } 
}
```

Is there any idea how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a fixed issue in [IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-158214) and/or [TestNG](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1084).

A fix will be available in the next TestNG release.